# Excel VBA programming

Tags: vba, excel

I am a complete beginner in excel and got an assignment today to be completed by tomorrow . I would be really grateful if someone can help me out in this .
I have a sheet which has the following table :

[image]

The first table is the master , from which i need to get the data and represent it the form of separate tables using marco-VBA . Would appreciate any help to achieve this using macro .Thanks.

Say the master table has n columns , so I need to form n-1 separate tables where each table will have 2 columns the first column will always be the first column of the master table and the second column will be (n+1)th column from the master table for the nth table . Example - 1st table will have 2 columns (1st column of master table and 2nd column of master table ) , likewise 2nd table will have 2 columns (1st column of master table and 3rd column of master table ) , so on and so forth ....

Comment: You didnt get this assignment today!

Comment: Got it today , am helpless , am a J2EE guy :P

Comment: Ah, assumed you were a student, apologies!

Comment: @richardtallent - FYI, homework tag is now blacklisted, please don't add it.

Comment: You haven't given us anywhere near enough information to help you.  The phrase "*i need to get the data and represent it the form of separate tables*" could mean anything.  Please clarify your question, *a lot*.  Tell us exactly what you want to produce as output and how it should be calculated.  Then we can tell you how to do that in VBA

Comment: Ok! apologies ! Say the master table has n columns , so I need to form n-1 separate tables where each table will have 2 columns the first column will always be the first column of the master table and the second column will be (n+1)th column from the master table for the nth table . Example - 1st table will have 2 columns (1st column of master table and 2nd column of master table ) , likewise 2nd table will have 2 columns (1st column of master table and 3rd column of master table ) , so on and so forth ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will be adding to this answer over the next hour or so.  The idea is for you to start with the early blocks of code while I develop later blocks.  **Edit** I have now completed the answer except for any extra explanations you might seek.

I agree with RBarryYoung: you do not provide enough information to allow anyone to provide you with a complete solution.  Also, if you are trying to learn VBA, giving you the solution will not help in the long term.

I would normally agree with djphatic: the macro recorder is very useful for learning the VBA that matches user operations but the macro recorder will not give you much of the VBA you need for this task.

I am curious who has given you this assignment when you are clearly not ready for it.

I cannot read your image so I created a worksheet which I named "MasterTable" and loaded it with data so it looks like:

[image: Sample data]

Your comments imply that this table may change in size so the first task is to identify its dimensions.  There are many different ways of identifying the dimensions of a table; none of which work in every situation.  I will use UsedRange.

Copy the following into a module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitTable1()

  Dim UsedRng As Range

  With Worksheets("MasterTable")

   Set UsedRng = .UsedRange
   Debug.Print UsedRng.Address
   Debug.Print UsedRng.Columns.Count
   Debug.Print UsedRng.Rows.Count

  End With

End Sub
```

There is no time to give full explanations of everything I will show you but I will try to explain the most important points.

`Option Explicit` means every variable must be declared.  Without this statement, a misspelt name will automatically declare a new variable.

`Debug.Print` outputs values to the Immediate window which should be at the bottom of the VBA Editor screen.  If it is not there, click `Ctrl`+`G`.

`Dim UsedRng As Range` declares a variable `UsedRng` of type `Range`.  A range is a type of Object.  When you assign a value to an object, you MUST start the statement with `Set`.

Running this macro will output the following to the Immediate window:

```
$A$1:$H$6
 8 
 6
```

I will not be using `UsedRng.Address` or `UsedRng.Columns.Count` but I wanted you to understand what the UsedRange is and how it can be used.

Add this macro to the module:

```
Sub SplitTable2()

  Dim CellValue() As Variant
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  With Worksheets("MasterTable")

   CellValue = .UsedRange.Value

   For RowCrnt = LBound(CellValue, 1) To UBound(CellValue, 1)
     Debug.Print "Row " & RowCrnt & ":";
     For ColCrnt = LBound(CellValue, 2) To UBound(CellValue, 2)
       Debug.Print " " & CellValue(RowCrnt, ColCrnt);
     Next
     Debug.Print
   Next

  End With

End Sub
```

`Dim CellValue() As Variant` declares a dynamic array, CellValue, of type Variant.  `()` means I will declare the size of the array at run time.

`CellValue = .UsedRange.Value` sets the array CellValue to the values within the UserRange.  This statement sets the dimensions of CellValue as required.

`CellValue` becomes a two dimensional array.  Normally the first dimension of an array would be the columns and the second the rows but this is not TRUE when the array is loaded from or to a range.

With a one dimensional array, `LBound(MyArray)` returns the lower bound of the array and `UBound(MyArray)` returns the upper bound.

With a two dimensional array, `LBound(MyArray, 1)` returns the lower bound of the first dimension of the array and `LBound(MyArray, 2)` returns the lower bound of the second dimension.

This macro outputs the following to the Immediate window.

```
Row 1: Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5 Column 6 Column 7 Column 8
Row 2: R1C1 R1C2 R1C3 R1C4 R1C5 R1C6 R1C7 R1C8
Row 3: R2C1 R2C2 R2C3 R2C4 R2C5 R2C6 R2C7 R2C8
Row 4: R3C1 R3C2 R3C3 R3C4 R3C5 R3C6 R3C7 R3C8
Row 5: R4C1 R4C2 R4C3 R4C4 R4C5 R4C6 R4C7 R4C8
Row 6: R5C1 R5C2 R5C3 R5C4 R5C5 R5C6 R5C7 R5C8
```

This second macro demonstrates that I can load all the values from the worksheet into an array and then output them.

Add this macro to the module:

```
Sub SplitTable3()

  Dim ColourBack As Long
  Dim ColourFont As Long

  With Worksheets("MasterTable")
    ColourBack = .Range("A1").Interior.Color
    ColourFont = .Range("A1").Font.Color
    Debug.Print ColourBack
    Debug.Print ColourFont
  End With

End Sub
```

Run this macro and it will output:

```
 16711680 
 16777215
```

For this answer, these are just magic numbers.  `16777215` sets the font colour to white and `16711680` sets the background or interior colour to blue.

For the last macro, I have created another worksheet "SplitTables".

Add this macro to the module:

```
Sub SplitTable4()

  Dim CellValue() As Variant
  Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
  Dim ColourBack As Long
  Dim ColourFont As Long
  Dim ColSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
  Dim RowDestStart As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long

  With Worksheets("MasterTable")
    ' Load required values from worksheet MasterTable
    CellValue = .UsedRange.Value
    With .Cells(.UsedRange.Row, .UsedRange.Column)
      ' Save the values from the top left cell of the used range.
      ' This allows for the used range being in the middle of the worksheet.
      ColourBack = .Interior.Color
      ColourFont = .Font.Color
    End With
  End With

  With Worksheets("SplitTables")

    ' Delete any existing contents of the worksheet
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete

    ' For this macro I need different variables for the source and destination
    ' columns. I do not need different variables for the source and destination
    ' rows but I have coded the macro as though I did.  This would allow the
    ' UsedRange in worksheet "MasterTable" to be in the middle of the worksheet
    ' and would allow the destination range to be anywhere within worksheet
    ' "SpltTables".

    ' Specify the first row and column of the first sub table.  You will
    ' probably want these both to be 1 for cell A1 but I want to show that my
    ' code will work if you want to start in the middle of the worksheet.
    ColDestCrnt = 2
    RowDestStart = 3

    ' I use LBound when I do not need to because I like to be absolutely
    ' explicit about what I am doing.  An array loaded from a range will
    ' always have lower bounds of one.

    For ColSrcCrnt = LBound(CellValue, 2) + 1 To UBound(CellValue, 2)
      ' Create one sub table from every column after the first.

      'Duplicate the colours of the header row in worksheet "MasterTable"
      With .Cells(RowDestStart, ColDestCrnt)
        .Interior.Color = ColourBack
        .Font.Color = ColourFont
      End With
      With .Cells(RowDestStart, ColDestCrnt + 1)
        .Interior.Color = ColourBack
        .Font.Color = ColourFont
      End With

      RowDestCrnt = RowDestStart

      For RowSrcCrnt = LBound(CellValue, 1) To UBound(CellValue, 1)
        ' For each row in CellValue, copy the values from the first and current
        ' columns to the sub table within worksheet "SplitTables"
        .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt).Value = _
                                    CellValue(RowSrcCrnt, LBound(CellValue, 2))
        .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt + 1).Value = _
                                              CellValue(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcCrnt)
        RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
      Next RowSrcCrnt
      ColDestCrnt = ColDestCrnt + 3     ' Advance to position of next sub table
    Next ColSrcCrnt

  End With

End Sub
```

This is the real macro.  All previous macros have served to demonstrate something.  This macro does what I think you want.

Come back with questions.  However, I do not know what time zone you are in.  It is 23:00 here.  I will be going to bed in about an hour.  After that questions will be answered tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir , even today when I look at this explanation , am at awe ! Very grateful to you Sir :)

Comment: @The New Idiot. I am glad you are still finding my answer useful. Although it is 11 years now, I remember how confused I was when I started with VBA.  With any answer, I try to explain the points I found difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the macro recorder within Excel. What you are looking to achieve looks like using VBA to perform simple copy and pastes on specific columns within a table. If you turn the macro recorder on and produce the first table by copying and pasting the variable and estimate columns then hit stop, you can view the code producing by viewing the Visual Basic Editor (Ctrl+F11).

You may find these links of some use:
http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/08/18/excel_cut_copy_paste_from_a_macro/
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/967

Comment: Thanks . but in case the table is dynamic like say n*m number of rows*columns ! Then !

Comment: For dynamic number of rows you can used named ranges using the OFFSET function. The dynamic columns is more difficult, as in the above you expect a specific result for each table. I have produced something in the past where a user selected the columns they required from the master table, the VBA then got the list of column names and looped through the master table to copy the appropriate columns.